# How do i track down "impossible" NPEs in Play Store Vitals?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash-reports

I have an app that has a good amount of installs over many years now and it seems that there will always be NPEs, no matter what i do.

The root of all those NPEs is a member variable object that suddenly no longer exists. Not just one, but in general some object, that is held by strong reference is suddenly gone. I have no idea what state the app was in or if it is caused by some "app killer" app or GC or...

I see several of these NPE entries in the play store "vitals" and some are even on the android system files that i have no access to. I am NOT a beginner and have a good understanding of java/android, that's why this puzzles me so much. Every version i add more and more guard functions and it reaches overkill but every single time when i check the vitals, i see an NPE "new in version x" of an old file that has not been changed and it is an object that HAS to be there.

Is there any way to track down the true reason for the removal ? or what is the general attitude towards those exceptions ?!

Edit:

We are not talking about ONE single NPE, we are talking about SEVERAL, each happening at less than 0.1% occurrence (according to the play store) throughout the entire app that consists of 20+ Activities and it all runs smoothly on all test devices over the years.

I assume it happens in various edge cases like the app being in the background for weeks or being in the background while short on memory etc but it does not tell me WHEN it happened (in the play store entry)

Comment: Can you provide Error prone Code block indicating the crash line ?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem typically turns out to be caused by a threading bug.  Two or more threads are sharing mutable objects or variables without adequate synchronization.   This can lead to race conditions, or more insidious problems caused by threads seeing stale values on memory reads.  (Read about the Java Memory Model.)

Unfortunately, there is no magic bullet solution to this:

- I don't know of any good (free) tools for analyzing a code-base for threading bugs.
- Finding them with trace printing or a debugger is difficult because a) these bugs tend to be difficult to reproduce, and b) these techniques tend to change the behavior of your program.
- Your best bet is to ask a expert to look at your code for you.
- Or become an expert yourself: starting by reading Goetz et al "Java Concurrency In Practice".
- Or become a *real* expert: get your head around JLS Chapter 17 ... particularly 17.4.

The best approach for avoiding this sort of problem is:

- get a thorough understanding of Java threads and synchronization,
- get a thorough understanding of the thread-safety requirements of framework / platform you are using (e.g. the Android app framework),
- avoid writing your own concurrency code: prefer the higher level classes provided by `java.util.concurrency.*`, and
- extensive automated testing.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: The classes involved are not used in a threaded way, just regular activities and their objects

Comment: So what kind of application is this?  Are you are aware that most if not all Android apps are *implicitly* multi-threaded?  Have you read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads ?

Comment: If two or more system threads share my activity object, how can the activity member variable be nulled by that ?

Comment: Due to one thread seeing a stale value; see the first paragraph of my answer!  (The thread that sees the `null` may be seeing the value of some variable that has been initialized, but the result of the initialization has not been flushed to main memory.  For example.)

Comment: But then it would be an android system bug. Usually u only have one UI Thread per process and that is what i have

Comment: Nope.  Do some reading.  Look at the leads I have given you. Or just trust that someone who has been writing Java code for 20+ years might have a clue.  Sorry, but I don't have the time / patience to try convince you.